# How to build PointCloudLibrary for Android with 1.13

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, pcl

I have a project need pcl to convert csv to ply (with some calculate) and tried build but it alway error like flann not included lz4, not found EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS ...

Seem because android build need arm64 library but when I install arm64 packages it is same.
I tried win win , mac m1, ubuntu x64 and ubuntu arm but not ok.
Have any one build successful with pcl 1.13 recently ? Or have any link contain pcl so file for android mobile ? software using this pcl lib is ok, too, I can extract so file.
Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: Note that I can build with ubuntu x64, mac m1 with cmake .. very easy because 3rd library can install by apt , brew